# Nested XSD definitions

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a problem with nesting XSDs. I have MAIN file with my document structure which has that same HEADer (i want to keep it separate - works well) and I want to have several bodies, depend on its content. 
My question is how to connect it in proper way?

MAIN.XSD:

```
<xs:schema id="MAIN" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns=""> 
  <xs:include schemaLocation="HEAD.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="MAIN">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
        <xs:element name="HEAD" type="HEADType"/>
        <xs:element name="BODY" type="BODYType"/>
      </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType> 
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

HEAD.XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="HEAD" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" >
  <xs:complexType name="HEADType">
    <xs:all minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
      <xs:element name="USER"> 
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[A-Z_]+"></xs:pattern>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Ideas I have are:

1. Make "MAIN" element in MAIN.xsd as type of MAINTYPE, then include MAIN.XSD into BODY_CUSTOMER which has defined BODYType.
2. Load MAIN.xsd and BODY_CUSTOMER.xsd separatly, and then it would find definition to BODYType.

But, I don't think it's the "proper" way to do it.

Comment: Use same file for HEAD and BODY! .. define BODYType in parallel to HEADType in `HEAD.XSD` (rename it to `HEADBODY.XSD`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, what you're trying to implement is colloquially referred to as "dangling definitions".

The most common problem with this approach is that typical XSD schema editors will complain about missing defitions when you're trying to edit Main.xsd

Your first idea is kind of confusing; still, I think it is not needed simply because the second one is really all you need to do. I would qualify that while `separately` refers to the files being distinct, you MUST load them at the same time. How you would do that depends on the tool which needs to consume the XSDs, so I can't really help you there.

Assuming .NET, if you load 3 XSD files at a time (Main, Head and  Body_Customer) in an [XmlSchemaSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx) object, it'll work exactly as you want.

As to "proper".... it is all depending on what is accepted or not as an XSD practice in your organization. As far as I am concerned, dangling types is a perfectly valid XSD design pattern.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I thought there is some way to connect xsd files that I know nothing about;)